# how to solve this differential equation $\tau\frac{dc}{dt} = -(1-\lambda)c(t) + \textbf{k}\cdot \textbf{h}(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I haven't solved diff eq in a very long time and I'm having trouble with the following differential equation:

$$\tau\frac{dc}{dt} = -(1-\lambda)c(t) + \textbf{k}\cdot \textbf{h}(t)$$

where $\textbf{k}$ and $\textbf{h}$ are vectors, and $\textbf{k}\cdot \textbf{h}(t)$ is the dot product of the two vectors. How do I separate $\textbf{h}$ from $\textbf{c}$ so I can integrate both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Duhamel formula, the scalar product is irrelevant. This will yield
$$
c(t)=c(0)e^{-\frac{1-\lambda}{\tau}t}+\frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^tdt'e^{-\frac{1-\lambda}{\tau}(t-t')}{\bf k\cdot h}(t').
$$
This solution can be obtained with the following procedure (Duhamel formula). Rewrite the equation as
$$
\frac{dc}{dt} = -\frac{1-\lambda}{\tau}c(t) + \frac{1}{\tau}\textbf{k}\cdot \textbf{h}(t).
$$
Then note that, without the last term, the homogeneous equation has the solution
$$
c_0(t)=c_0(0)e^{-\frac{1-\lambda}{\tau}t}.
$$
So, you assume that your equation would have a solution given by
$$
c(t)=u(t)e^{-\frac{1-\lambda}{\tau}t}.
$$
Put this into the given equation and you are left with
$$
\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{1}{\tau}\textbf{k}\cdot \textbf{h}(t)e^{\frac{1-\lambda}{\tau}t}
$$
that is very easy to solve giving the final solution written at the beginning.

Comment: the book I'm using says $$c(t) = \frac{\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{h}}{1-\lambda} (1-e^{\frac{-t(1-\lambda)}{\tau}}) + c(0)e^{-\frac{1-\lambda}{\tau}t}$$. Maybe the book is assuming some stuff but is there a way to find the solution without the integral?

Comment: This is the right solution when ${\bf h}$ is a constant. You can check it straightforwardly.

Comment: In the answer a $1/\tau$ was missing. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but could you elaborate how to plug things into the Lommel formula? I found it here(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lommel_function) but I am still confused what bessel function of first and second kind are.

Comment: I have extended the answer with the derivation of the solution.

Comment: Sorry, it was not Lommel but Duhamel formula. I fixed this.